# .spread with data redirect

Tags: javascript, promise

When developing for databases, method `spread` is indispensable, converting array values into named parameters.

But how to do the same when resolved data cannot be mapped directly?

Here's a simple example of a nested transaction:

```
db.tx(function () {
    return promise.all([
        this.none("update users set active=$1 where id=$2", [true, 123]),
        this.none("insert into audit(status, id) values($1, $2)", ['active', 123]),
        this.tx(function () {
            return promise.all([
                this.one("insert into users(name) values($1) returning id", "John"),
                this.one("insert into events(code) values($1) returning id", 123)
            ]);
        })
    ]);
})
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data[2][0].id); // print new user id;
        console.log(data[2][1].id); // print new event id;
    });
```

I would really like to be able to replace the last `then` section with the `spread`, but the problem is we cannot use the data directly, we need to use `data[2]` in our example.

What would be the recommended approach to get an effect of:

```
.spread(data[2], function (user, event) {
    console.log(user.id); // print new user id;
    console.log(event.id); // print new event id;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.get(2).spread(function(user, event) { ... })
```